# How to properly initialize a vector in Rust, given that the vector will be immutable after the initialization?

Tags: vector, rust

What is a good way to initialize the vector, without the `mut` keyword, given that the vector will be immutable after the initialization?

For example:

```rust
// nums is a `i32` vector(Vec<i32>)
// here is to pad two 1s with both ends
let mut padded: Vec<i32> = vec![0; len_p];
padded[0] = 1;
padded[len_n + 1] = 1;
for (idx, &num) in nums.iter().enumerate(){
    padded[idx + 1] = num;
}
// `padded` will be read-only/immutable ever since
```

Otherwise, to mark `padded` `mut`, simply to initialize it, seems to me a waste of immutability, since I cannot enforce it after the initialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common idiom seen in Rust is to introduce a local scope for just this purpose.

```
let padded: Vec<i32> = {
  let mut tmp: Vec<i32> = vec![0; len_p];
  tmp[0] = 1;
  tmp[len_n + 1] = 1;
  for (idx, &num) in nums.iter().enumerate(){
    tmp[idx + 1] = num;
  }
  tmp
};
```

Inside the nested scope, we have a local variable called `tmp` which is mutable. Then, when we get to the end of that scope, we pass ownership of that vector to the *immutable* variable `padded`. The compiler is free to (and likely will) optimize out any actual movement that's happening, and this will compile to something as efficient as what you wrote. But from the borrow checker's perspective, `tmp` is mutable and `padded` is immutable, as desired. Once `tmp` goes out of scope, there's no way to modify `padded` anymore.

Remember, the owner of a value always determines whether or not that value is mutable, so when you pass ownership to someone else, they're free to change the mutability of the value upon taking ownership.

Comment: If `padded` is supposed to be immutable forever (i.e. not moved and then mutated elsewhere) it might also be a good idea to make it's type `Box<[i32]>` by calling `tmp.into_boxed_slice()` at the end of the scope.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways:

1. Most functional (FP) approach: Use **collect**

```rust
let v: Vec<i32> = std::iter::once(1).chain(
      nums.iter().copied()
   )
   .collect();
```

2. Initialize in scope. Useful when you need some extra variables which would be cleaned up after this.

```rust
let v = {
  let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![0; len_p];
  v[0] = 1;
  v[len_n + 1] = 1;
  for (&src, dst) in nums.iter().zip(v[1..].iter_mut()){
     *dst = src;
  }
  v
}
```

3. Rebind name and move vector into it. Useful when initialization is clear and simple.

```rust
  let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![0; len_p];
  v[0] = 1;
  v[len_n + 1] = 1;
  for (&src, dst) in nums.iter().zip(v[1..].iter_mut()){
     *dst = src;
  }
  // Rebind to immutable variable
  let v = v;
  // Cannot mutate here
```